# How to get data from IMDb using BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the names of top 250 IMDb movies using BeautifulSoup. The code does not execute properly and shows no errors.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top"

response = requests.get(url)

rc = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(rc,"html.parser")

for i in soup.find_all("td",{"class:":"titleColumn"}):
    print(i)
```

I'm expecting it show me all of the td tags with titleColumn classes but it is not working. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `:` after the `class`:

```
{"class:":"titleColumn"}
```

to

```
{"class":"titleColumn"}
```

**Example ++**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top"
response = requests.get(url)

rc = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(rc,"html.parser")

data = []

for i in soup.find_all("td",{"class":"titleColumn"}):
    data.append({
        'people':i.a['title'],
        'title':i.a.get_text(),
        'info':i.span.get_text()
    })
    
data
```

Comment: Thanks! I was expecting a syntax error or as such but since nothing came out, I couldn't figure it out on my own! :)